# Lazy Load - $(document).ready?

Tags: jquery, performance, wordpress, lazy-loading

Can I just use jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){ //content });` and a quick solution for lazy loading?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: Our stat and ads JS hold up the page load so I want those two things to load after everything else.

Comment: Then you don't want lazy loading, but you do want $(document).ready processing. With some care, this can be done nicely from this.

Answer (score 3):

`$(document).ready` does not give lazy loading. What it does is wait for the page elements to finish loading before running the script - which is very useful and important when the code is manipulating elements in the page.

Lazy loading strictly would involve loading parts of the page or the data only on demand, only when needed. If you actually need lazy loading, you need to do it properly. If you just need the page elements to have loaded then `$(document).ready` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

All the handlers passed to `$(document).ready` method are executed once the DOM in ready so it is not going to help with lazy loading. For lazy loading you might have to write your own logic.